# Conditional Lock Cell , unable to sort

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a macro that will lock any cell greater than 0. When I run the code below it works but locks the 1st row where I have a drop down arrow that does sorting and number filters. Is there a way to add to this code so that the first row wont be locked?

```
Sub Test()
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim MyPlage As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        .Unprotect
        .Cells.Locked = False
        Set MyPlage = .Range("J2:AA1074")
        For Each Cell In MyPlage
            If Not IsError(Cell) Then
                If Cell.Value > "0" Then
                    Cell.Locked = True
                End If
            End If
        Next
        .Protect
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not define your range accordingly then? Instead of `.Range("J2:AA1074")`, use `.Range("J3:AA1074")`

Comment: @SiddharthRout, I've just found that I can't sort column using AutoFilter if there is any locked cell in sorting range (when sheet is protected)..so, it doesn't help..

Comment: What is your question? `1` Ensure that Row 1 is not locked? Or `2` Unable to sort if there is a locked cell OR Both?

Comment: @SiddharthRout, as I understand, OP wants to unclock first row and then be able to sort values using autofilter

Comment: @simoco: I thought so. Just wanted to confirm before posting as my answer is already ready :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout, interesting to read it:) because I can't find any other solutions exept using `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event for unprotecting sheet when first row is selected:)

Comment: Amending my post. Misunderstood.

Comment: Any other help would be appreciated, I tried changing it to J3 but still cant access sorting drop down.

Comment: does your autofilter in first row or in second?

Comment: I would like to ensure that row1 is unlocked and then apply the same code as above to lock the cells greater than 0

Comment: My autofilter is in row 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add following code to the `Sheet module` (change `Range("J1:AA1")` to the range with your autofilter):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Application.Intersect(Target, Range("J1:AA1")) Is Nothing Then
        ActiveSheet.Protect
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: LOL. You already posted an answer. There is another method using `Allow Users to Edit Ranges` which allows sorting cells in protected mode. I was just updating that :)

Comment: I am amending the answer. One moment.

Answer (score 2):

The most simplest was is to define your range which doesn't include the Top Row :)

Change

```
.Range("J2:AA1074")
```

to

```
.Range("J3:AA1074")
```

Also, Instead of looping through every cell in the range and checking if that cell has an error or not, you can directly use `SpecialCells`. For example (**TRIED AND TESTED**)

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim Cell As Range, MyPlage As Range, FinalRange As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        .Unprotect
        .Cells.Locked = False

        On Error Resume Next
        Set MyPlage = .Range("J3:AA1074").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not MyPlage Is Nothing Then
            For Each Cell In MyPlage
                If Cell.Value > 0 Then Cell.Locked = True
            Next
        End If

        .Protect DrawingObjects:=True, _
                 Contents:=True, _
                 Scenarios:=True, _
                 AllowFiltering:=True, _
                 AllowSorting:=True

        .EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
    End With
End Sub
```

To ensure that Autofilter and Sorting works, specify it in `.Protect` as I have done above.

Before you run the above code, you also need to take one extra step.

1. Unprotect the worksheet if it is already protected
2. Under Review Tab, click on "Allow Users to Edit Ranges"
3. Add "New" range
4. Select the range you want allow users to sort

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: I've thought about this and even tried it, but it doesn't work for me (excel 2013). When I have locked cell in sorting range it doesn't work or I've missed something?

Comment: Tested it in Excel 2010. Let me boot into in win 8 (which has excel 2013) to test it.

Comment: I didn't say about filtering, I said about sorting using autofilter:) Filter works for me, but not sorting

Comment: Thanks, When I try this I get type mismatch. Some values are #NA (errors) I think this needs to be bypassed?

Comment: @user1342164: I have amended my post. Now Try it.

Comment: @SiddharthRout, works now:) and it was the first time I noticed `Allow Users to Edit Ranges` menu item:)

Comment: @SiddharthRout, there is little disadvantage of your approach: user can edit locked cells:)

Comment: @simoco: Seems you missed the little piece of code `.EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells` ;)